# GL_LINES and FXAA in WebGL

Tags: glsl, shader, antialiasing, fxaa

So I have this problem with FXAA. The lines I draw using GL_LINES look, well, not really anti-aliased after applying FXAA as a post-process filter, they just look blurred. So my Question basically is - is this the espected bahaviour of FXAA with GL_LINES? The shader code I'm using is nothing special ([See here](http://www.geeks3d.com/20110405/fxaa-fast-approximate-anti-aliasing-demo-glsl-opengl-test-radeon-geforce/3/))

This is how the FXAA output looks:

[image: fxaa]

And here is the (standard 4x) MSAA:

[image]

Comment: [The image](http://www.ozone3d.net/public/jegx/201104/fxaa_demo_05.jpg) in the article you posted also looks similar by the way and there's mention of an improved version in the comments.

Comment: @MarcoA. Yes, that is, in fact, why I suspect it to be the expected result. As for the improved version mentioned in the comment - I'm aware fo V2 and V3 of FXAA, however I would like to keep using the simplest version possible, which is V2 (http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=nvidia_fxaa&num=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No matter the fact that it has "antialiasing" in its name, FXAA is *not* really antialiasing. "Real" antialiasing techniques involve taking multiple samples of the signal; FXAA, as a post-processing technique cannot do that.

At the end of the day, it is nothing more than a smart blur filter. So while there may be variations of it that can handle lines better, it's still just a blur filter.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly the same conclusion that I reached and I wanted get a second opinion on. I'm now tweaking it a bit to get better results. The changes that Lottes introduced in 3.11 are quite helpful (https://gist.github.com/bkaradzic/6011431)